# Проверка на наличие значения в атрибуте lang тега <html>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, if, attr

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите плз, не могу разобраться почему не работает условие.

Ситуация в следующем, имеется интернет магазин на 5ти языках, при переходе на любой из языков, в теге html заполняется атрибут lang соответствующий выбранному языку ru, en, lv и т.д., таким образом:

```
<html lang='ru'>
```

мне необходимо, чтобы при смене языка, и сопутствующей смене значения атрибута lang, моему div, с классом page-wrapper присваивался класс языка, пишу код:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    if ($('html').attr('lang','ru')){
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass('russian');
        } 
    if ($('html').attr('lang','en')){
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass('english');
        } 
    if ($('html').attr('lang','lv')){
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass('latvian');
        } 
    if ($('html').attr('lang','lt')){
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass('lithuanian');
        } 
    if ($('html').attr('lang','et')){
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass('estonian');
        }   
});
```

Не работает =(

Происходит присваивание всех классов сразу

```
<div class='russian english latvian lithuanian estonian'>
```

Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Comment: А можно спросить, для чего это надо? Если задача классов "russian" и т.д. чисто стилевая, то вам ,возможно, будет достаточно изменить селекторы с `.russian` на `html[lang="ru"] .page-wrapper`, например...

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('html').attr('lang') == 'ru'){
  ...
```

и так далее.

---

Ваш вызов

```
if ($('html').attr('lang','ru')){
```

(и другие) проверяет результат, возвращаемый вызовом `$('html').attr(...)` с двумя параметрами (который, кстати говоря, устанавливает значение атрибута), на соответствие булевскому `true`. Так как этот результат - тот же объект-обертка `$('html')`, его булевское значение всегда равно `true`. Поэтому Ваш код добавляет все классы.